# Reputation points conflict in summary and detail views

Tags: support, reputation, negative-rep

I'm trying to understand why a number of reputation points show as negative in my summary and positive in my detail views:

[image]

It looks like I received the 3rd upvote that day, which would explain all 3 +5 increases, but I can't understand why the summary shows as a -25 decrease on that day instead.

Comment: Bounry? Deleted user? I see +25 for that day...

Comment: With all due respect, I don't understand the downvote on this type of question. It's seeking an explanation of a situation rather than stating something inaccurate, so it isn't "wrong." It's well-written and includes illustrations to give it clarity, so it's not "low quality." It's a situation that could happen to a number of users, and it elicited a concise and helpful response. I'm a fairly new user genuinely trying to learn the criteria for downvoting on Meta. Thanks!

Comment: Totally agree with @Sue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You started a 50 reputation bounty on that question. After the bounty started, you collected 5 upvotes on it, gaining you back 25 of the 50 reputation you spent, for a net total of 25 reputation lost. The date displayed is just the date of the most recent event in the series going into that particular calculation. Since your reputation history is fairly inactive, events from much older dates (in this case, the bounty being back in November of 2014) are being included in your dropdown.

Comment: Ok, it'd been clearer if I was shown the -50 debit and then the +25 credit rather than a consolidated balance with a totally unrelated date with the original transaction.